# What is the source of the mantra "Om Aryamayai Namah"?

Tags: gods, mantras, vedic-gods, brahmacharya, deity

A lot of websites and youtube channels related to Brahmacharya recommend meditating on this mantra "Om Aryamayai Namah".
I am curious as to what is it's source and who is the deity of the mantra.

Comment: I believe it has nothing to do with Hinduism or communist propaganda. But I'll wait for an expert from the region to answer that properly.

Comment: It looks like Aditya Aryaman's Mantra for Pitris. I guess..

Answer (score 0):

It should be अर्यमायै

Aryamaa अर्यमा/अर्यम aka आर्यमन् or विधाता would be the first choice for the Deva. I'm not aware of the source, however.

He's one of the 12 Aadityas, the second, in particular, just before Mitra(3rd) and Varuna(4th) and after Dhaataa(1st).

Comment: अर्यमायै - which vibhakti is this? kindly clarify.

Comment: @estimator I'm not aware of that since I haven't studied much (or any) Sanskrit grammar. But, this sort of transformation isn't rare. दुर्गा --> दुर्गायै -- सरस्वती --> सरस्वत्यै etc.